# Error In Runtime From Terser During Build --prod

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

I have updated everything Angular and am now getting the error below (4x) when I
"Build --prod"

No errors if I remove --prod

I have no real code in this app. It is just a starter shell.

Any suggestions on what to look into?

```
ERROR in runtime.82c6613acef8f7246fe8.js from Terser
TypeError: Cannot read property 'minify' of undefined
    at minify (/Users/puser/Dropbox/AngularApps/GenesisFYI-v06/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/minify.js:175:23)
    at module.exports (/Users/puser/Dropbox/AngularApps/GenesisFYI-v06/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/worker.js:13:40)
    at handle (/Users/puser/Dropbox/AngularApps/GenesisFYI-v06/node_modules/worker-farm/lib/child/index.js:44:8)
    at process.<anonymous> (/Users/puser/Dropbox/AngularApps/GenesisFYI-v06/node_modules/worker-farm/lib/child/index.js:51:3)
    at process.emit (events.js:197:13)
    at emit (internal/child_process.js:828:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/next_tick.js:76:17)
```

---

My current Version

```
Angular CLI: 7.3.0  
Node: 11.8.0  
OS: darwin x64  
Angular: 7.2.3  
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms  
... http, language-service, platform-browser  
... platform-browser-dynamic, router, service-worker  

Package                           Version  
-----------------------------------------------------------  
@angular-devkit/architect         0.13.0  
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.13.0  
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.13.0  
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.13.0  
@angular-devkit/core              0.6.8  
@angular-devkit/schematics        0.6.8  
@angular/cli                      7.3.0  
@angular/pwa                      0.6.8  
@ngtools/webpack                  7.3.0  
@schematics/angular               0.6.8  
@schematics/update                0.13.0  
rxjs                              6.4.0  
typescript                        3.2.4  
webpack                           4.29.0
```

Comment: Note: Running this works "ng build --prod --optimization=false"

Comment: I've encountered the same issue like 20 minutes ago. The problem was that I had removed `package-lock.json` file.

Comment: Thanks @Nuurek. Unfortunately, mine is there. And I did a npm Install just to try and rebuild it.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It seems to be a problem with the recently released version 3.16 of Terser, [here's](https://github.com/terser-js/terser/issues/251) the related issue in Terser and in [Terser as a Webpack plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/terser-webpack-plugin/issues/66).

In [this VueJS issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/3407#issuecomment-459985313) they recommended to **downgrade it to version 3.14.1.** You can do it looking for the line in `package.json` containing `"terser"` and pin it as follows:

```
    "terser": "3.14.1",
```

Comment: Thanks @pietro. I'll go look at that. I don't THINK I am setting the Terser version anywhere in my Angular config. I think that is pulled in from webpack. So let me go play.

Comment: We had to pin it in `package.json` in `dependencies` as follows: `"terser": "^3.14.1"`. I think by default it pulls the latest version.

Comment: Thank you @Pietro! That seems to have worked. I added "terser": "3.14.1" to my dependencies (no caret on mine), npm install, then the build with --prod worked.

Comment: I did not have "terser" in my package, but I added it to devDependencies, and it solved my problem. Maybe I was using some other npm module depending on terser.

Answer (score 10):

As Pietro Saccardi said, by now, it's necessary to fix the Terser version to 3.14.1 in the package.json as follows:
`"terser": "3.14.1"`

Don't use the `^` in the version or it could upgrade to 3.16.

Answer (score 4):

For Angular prod build, this fixed it for me:

```
npm install --save-exact --save terser@3.14
```

Answer (score 2):

The above answers are correct. Terser plugin is required to downgrade to version 3.14.1. But here is the procedure for doing that :

1. Open package-lock.json file.
2. Replace the version of terser to 3.14.1. Refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54499681/8293506) for where to make changes.
3. open cmd and run the command `npm install terser@3.14.1`.
4. Now you can run `ng build --prod` for production build.

Answer (score 2):

I'm in Angular 11, in my case it gave the same error, but it was my mistake: in angular.json I didn't import the styles and scripts correctly ("styles": [], "scripts": []),always check if the imports of your project are correct, because if it is wrong, this same error will appear.

Comment: Thank you boss! I almost spent a day to resolve it and did many things...but no luck . finally checked  ("styles": [], "scripts": []) and resloved my issue.

Comment: I'm glad it helped you, at the time I wasted 3 days trying.

Answer (score 1):

To resolve the angular prod build issue, we need to fix the version of **terser** and **terser-webpack-plugin** to **3.14.1** in the package-lock.json. Below is what my looks like. Finally the production build is working for me.

```
  "terser": {
  "version": "3.14.1",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/terser/-/terser-3.14.1.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-NSo3E99QDbYSMeJaEk9YW2lTg3qS9V0aKGlb+PlOrei1X02r1wSBHCNX/O+yeTRFSWPKPIGj6MqvvdqV4rnVGw==",
  "dev": true,
  "requires": {
    "commander": "2.17.1",
    "source-map": "0.6.1",
    "source-map-support": "0.5.9"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "source-map": {
      "version": "0.6.1",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/source-map/-/source-map-0.6.1.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-UjgapumWlbMhkBgzT7Ykc5YXUT46F0iKu8SGXq0bcwP5dz/h0Plj6enJqjz1Zbq2l5WaqYnrVbwWOWMyF3F47g==",
      "dev": true
    }
  }
},
"terser-webpack-plugin": {
  "version": "1.1.0",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/terser-webpack-plugin/-/terser-webpack-plugin-1.1.0.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-61lV0DSxMAZ8AyZG7/A4a3UPlrbOBo8NIQ4tJzLPAdGOQ+yoNC7l5ijEow27lBAL2humer01KLS6bGIMYQxKoA==",
  "dev": true,
  "requires": {
    "cacache": "11.3.2",
    "find-cache-dir": "2.0.0",
    "schema-utils": "1.0.0",
    "serialize-javascript": "1.6.1",
    "source-map": "0.6.1",
    "terser": "3.14.1",
    "webpack-sources": "1.3.0",
    "worker-farm": "1.6.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "cacache": {
      "version": "11.3.2",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/cacache/-/cacache-11.3.2.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-E0zP4EPGDOaT2chM08Als91eYnf8Z+eH1awwwVsngUmgppfM5jjJ8l3z5vO5p5w/I3LsiXawb1sW0VY65pQABg==",
      "dev": true,
      "requires": {
        "bluebird": "3.5.3",
        "chownr": "1.1.1",
        "figgy-pudding": "3.5.1",
        "glob": "7.1.3",
        "graceful-fs": "4.1.15",
        "lru-cache": "5.1.1",
        "mississippi": "3.0.0",
        "mkdirp": "0.5.1",
        "move-concurrently": "1.0.1",
        "promise-inflight": "1.0.1",
        "rimraf": "2.6.3",
        "ssri": "6.0.1",
        "unique-filename": "1.1.1",
        "y18n": "4.0.0"
      }
    },
    "find-cache-dir": {
      "version": "2.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/find-cache-dir/-/find-cache-dir-2.0.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-LDUY6V1Xs5eFskUVYtIwatojt6+9xC9Chnlk/jYOOvn3FAFfSaWddxahDGyNHh0b2dMXa6YW2m0tk8TdVaXHlA==",
      "dev": true,
      "requires": {
        "commondir": "1.0.1",
        "make-dir": "1.3.0",
        "pkg-dir": "3.0.0"
      }
    },
    "find-up": {
      "version": "3.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/find-up/-/find-up-3.0.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-1yD6RmLI1XBfxugvORwlck6f75tYL+iR0jqwsOrOxMZyGYqUuDhJ0l4AXdO1iX/FTs9cBAMEk1gWSEx1kSbylg==",
      "dev": true,
      "requires": {
        "locate-path": "3.0.0"
      }
    },
    "locate-path": {
      "version": "3.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/locate-path/-/locate-path-3.0.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-7AO748wWnIhNqAuaty2ZWHkQHRSNfPVIsPIfwEOWO22AmaoVrWavlOcMR5nzTLNYvp36X220/maaRsrec1G65A==",
      "dev": true,
      "requires": {
        "p-locate": "3.0.0",
        "path-exists": "3.0.0"
      }
    },
    "lru-cache": {
      "version": "5.1.1",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/lru-cache/-/lru-cache-5.1.1.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-KpNARQA3Iwv+jTA0utUVVbrh+Jlrr1Fv0e56GGzAFOXN7dk/FviaDW8LHmK52DlcH4WP2n6gI8vN1aesBFgo9w==",
      "dev": true,
      "requires": {
        "yallist": "3.0.3"
      }
    },
    "mississippi": {
      "version": "3.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/mississippi/-/mississippi-3.0.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-x471SsVjUtBRtcvd4BzKE9kFC+/2TeWgKCgw0bZcw1b9l2X3QX5vCWgF+KaZaYm87Ss//rHnWryupDrgLvmSkA==",
      "dev": true,
      "requires": {
        "concat-stream": "1.6.2",
        "duplexify": "3.6.1",
        "end-of-stream": "1.4.1",
        "flush-write-stream": "1.0.3",
        "from2": "2.3.0",
        "parallel-transform": "1.1.0",
        "pump": "3.0.0",
        "pumpify": "1.5.1",
        "stream-each": "1.2.3",
        "through2": "2.0.5"
      }
    },
    "p-limit": {
      "version": "2.1.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/p-limit/-/p-limit-2.1.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-NhURkNcrVB+8hNfLuysU8enY5xn2KXphsHBaC2YmRNTZRc7RWusw6apSpdEj3jo4CMb6W9nrF6tTnsJsJeyu6g==",
      "dev": true,
      "requires": {
        "p-try": "2.0.0"
      }
    },
    "p-locate": {
      "version": "3.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/p-locate/-/p-locate-3.0.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-x+12w/To+4GFfgJhBEpiDcLozRJGegY+Ei7/z0tSLkMmxGZNybVMSfWj9aJn8Z5Fc7dBUNJOOVgPv2H7IwulSQ==",
      "dev": true,
      "requires": {
        "p-limit": "2.1.0"
      }
    },
    "p-try": {
      "version": "2.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/p-try/-/p-try-2.0.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-hMp0onDKIajHfIkdRk3P4CdCmErkYAxxDtP3Wx/4nZ3aGlau2VKh3mZpcuFkH27WQkL/3WBCPOktzA9ZOAnMQQ==",
      "dev": true
    },
    "pkg-dir": {
      "version": "3.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/pkg-dir/-/pkg-dir-3.0.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-/E57AYkoeQ25qkxMj5PBOVgF8Kiu/h7cYS30Z5+R7WaiCCBfLq58ZI/dSeaEKb9WVJV5n/03QwrN3IeWIFllvw==",
      "dev": true,
      "requires": {
        "find-up": "3.0.0"
      }
    },
    "pump": {
      "version": "3.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/pump/-/pump-3.0.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-LwZy+p3SFs1Pytd/jYct4wpv49HiYCqd9Rlc5ZVdk0V+8Yzv6jR5Blk3TRmPL1ft69TxP0IMZGJ+WPFU2BFhww==",
      "dev": true,
      "requires": {
        "end-of-stream": "1.4.1",
        "once": "1.4.0"
      }
    },
    "source-map": {
      "version": "0.6.1",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/source-map/-/source-map-0.6.1.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-UjgapumWlbMhkBgzT7Ykc5YXUT46F0iKu8SGXq0bcwP5dz/h0Plj6enJqjz1Zbq2l5WaqYnrVbwWOWMyF3F47g==",
      "dev": true
    },
    "ssri": {
      "version": "6.0.1",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/ssri/-/ssri-6.0.1.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-3Wge10hNcT1Kur4PDFwEieXSCMCJs/7WvSACcrMYrNp+b8kDL1/0wJch5Ni2WrtwEa2IO8OsVfeKIciKCDx/QA==",
      "dev": true,
      "requires": {
        "figgy-pudding": "3.5.1"
      }
    },
    "yallist": {
      "version": "3.0.3",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/yallist/-/yallist-3.0.3.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-S+Zk8DEWE6oKpV+vI3qWkaK+jSbIK86pCwe2IF/xwIpQ8jEuxpw9NyaGjmp9+BoJv5FV2piqCDcoCtStppiq2A==",
      "dev": true
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Solution for Yarn and Angular 7+

1. Add terser v3.14.1 to package.json

   `yarn add terser@3.14.1`
2. Remove `yarn.lock` file
3. Run Yarn again

   `yarn`
4. Build your project

   `ng build --prod`

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes changing only terser dev dependency will not work.

After adding "terser": "3.14.1" in dev dependencies. The error may arise as follows
ERROR in scripts.56c939869e47ec340102.js from Terser
Unexpected token: punc (:) [scripts.56c939869e47ec340102.js:10369,11]

For me, the error got resolved after removing map files from the scripts which I have included. It might help you also.

Comment: looking at the message I would say this is a different issue. You probably should open your own separate question. By adding it here as an answer I believe few people will see it.

Comment: Or search for this - there look to be several answers -  Terser Unexpected token: punc (:)

Answer (score 0):

Terser can be disabled as well with:

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  optimization: {
    minimize: false
  }
};
```

Reference: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/optimization/#optimizationminimize

Comment: likewise via angular.json ->   configurations:production:            "optimization": false,

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was ([ref](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/20773#issuecomment-841341889)):

1. Deleted the specific reference I had to webpack from package.json
2. Deleted package-lock.json
3. Ran npm install
4. Ran ng update @angular/core@12 @angular/cli@12

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the error was caused by having a CSS file reference in the *angular.json*'s *scripts* section. Checking the integrity and content of your **styles and scripts sections** might solve the problem for you too.

This problem was also signaled in a console error when running the app.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, Terser was not in package.json file and it was a dependency for

```
@angular-devkit/build-angular
```

In order to get rid of this annoying error I had to set optimization false in the angular.json file!

```
     "configurations": {
            "development": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.dev.ts"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "optimization": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "buildOptimizer": false
            },
    }
```