# ERROR in scrips.xxx.js from Terser Invalid assignment

Tags: angular, ng-build, terser

I am on angular 7.2.13. After the command "ng build --prod" I get an error:

```
$ ng build --prod

Date: 2019-04-18T11:50:54.572Z
Hash: 87e16a832fe7eaf96031
Time: 91438ms
chunk {0} runtime.b57bf819d5bdce77f1c7.js (runtime) 1.41 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {1} es2015-polyfills.9bd4f46a9b972fb5c7b6.js (es2015-polyfills) 56.4 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {2} main.01281eab5e13b865ee55.js (main) 1.17 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {3} polyfills.f1a86b50434b1a515c5a.js (polyfills) 41 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {4} styles.504a1c33fb09fcab2835.css (styles) 80 bytes [initial] [rendered]
chunk {scripts} scripts.5f11b62514f5238edd2a.js (scripts) 612 kB [entry] [rendered]
```

> ERROR in scripts.5f11b62514f5238edd2a.js from Terser
>   Invalid assignment [scripts.5f11b62514f5238edd2a.js:21,32]

I have already tried to change terser to 3.14.1 in package.json as other threads says to do or install terser via npm. I also tried to install terser version 3.16.1 because threads says it resolve the bug from terser.

But none of this worked...

This is just an example of what I tried :

package.json :

```
"devDependencies": {
    ---
    "terser": "3.14.1",
    ---
  }
```

package-lock.json :

```
"terser": {
      "version": "3.14.1",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/terser/-/terser-3.14.1.tgz",
       ---
```

I want to build my application but I can't because of this error...

Comment: Terser can be disabled as well. Refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62027324/6868861)

Comment: Terser can be disabled as well.
check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62027324/6868861)

Answer (score 3):

Finally I found the problem. It was a .js file which was in my project (in a js foder in assets)) and this file wasn't used. I deleted it and then it worked!

I found this by made a new angular project and copy paste files into it progressivly and make ng build --prod after each file. I was able to determinate whith this method which one was making the terser error.